# async http request such that response time doesn't increase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a rails code, where I am trying to talk to the server and passing requests. I have to get logs from the server (by sending a http request to the server) but I don't want to increase the time taken for request processing, is there any way I can get the info such that it doesn't increase my request processing time?

```
# connect to the server
# make a request to the server
# after the request is completed, get info
# server shuts down
# output the results
```

How can I make the info fetching asynchronous such that it doesn't increase the time taken to output the results?

How can I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want a controller method to make some external web request and then have the same controller method return the response, there is no other option than to wait.

If you're less strict about these requirements, you have a couple options:

1. Don't call the external request in the controller. Render a HTML page immediately and make the request in Javascript using AJAX. Note that this might not be an option if the external request you're trying to hit has CORS restrictions - in this case, making the external request needs to be done on the sever (in Ruby). Note that you could get around the CORS limitation by making a Rails controller action that makes the external request, and calling this Rails endpoint from AJAX.
2. Use a true async / background job method in Ruby - Resque, for example.
   However this method is going to be more difficult than option 1. You're still going to need your Rails controller to render a HTML without the async-loaded data. Then, as part of the code running asynchronously, you can trigger one of your Rails endpoints that pushes a websocket update to the client. This is the most "realtime" option but like I said, is more difficult.
3. Probably the easiest solution is to cache the response of your external request so that it doesn't need to be repeatedly called. For example you could call the request as part of your Rails initialization code and then save the response to the database. This method will not work if you need to call a different external request each time the Rails controller is hit. To take this a step further, you might even pre-load all the data your app is going to need from the external resource and then use an ORM to load different data for each request. Since HTTP latency is much larger than SQL latency, this would make things a lot faster.